# Unable to install php7.1-bcmath on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, php, laravel

I'm trying to install a Laravel package name [bitwasp](https://packagist.org/packages/bitwasp/bitcoin) but this package depends on `bcmath`. Whenever I tried to install it gave me an error. Also I tried to install it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath
```

But whenever I do this, I got the following error also my Ubuntu is 17.10:

```
After this operation, 128 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-gd amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-bz2 amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-opcache amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-json amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-mcrypt amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-zip amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-curl amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-xml amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-mbstring amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-mysql amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-readline amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php7.1 amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-cli amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-common amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-bcmath amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-gd_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-bz2_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-opcache_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-json_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-mcrypt_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-zip_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-curl_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-xml_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-mbstring_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-mysql_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-readline_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/libapache2-mod-php7.1_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-cli_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-common_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-bcmath_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Already run `update` and `fix-missing` and nothing happens, every time I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
# apt update
# apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

Restart apache and all good to go:

```
# service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Your package manager seems to think these packages are in the ppa you seem to use, but they are not.

See the [list of artful packages here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=artful)

It seems your `apt-get`package management wants to install everything from this ppa.

The first thing to do is remove it*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php
```

and/or

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php
```

then update the repos

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and this would be a good spot to clean up apt with

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then install your packages with

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath
```

This should work - if not, you have other issues with your `sources.list`.

If you look into your sources list with your favorite editor

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You should see something similar to this.

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
```

If not, copy/replace this sources list and replace the `de` with your country code. There is also a pretty good [Ubuntu wiki entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) on handling repository sources.

(*)*You can re-enable it at anytime with `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt-get update`*

Answer (score 0):

install this : 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/artful/amd64/php7.1-bcmath/download

add this :

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main universe
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install php7.1-bcmath
```